# Check if at least one checkboxlist is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have checkboxlist and I would like to check if at least one checkbox is checked.  If none is checked then I want to show alert message that says please select at least one item.  I want to do this in code behind if possible.  I have started but don't know if it is right or wrong but not able to finish it.

```
 public void alert()
    {
        foreach (ListItem listItem in cblCustomerList.Items)
        {
            if (!listItem.Selected)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

here is the checkboxlist in aspx:

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblCustomerList" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CssClass="CheckBoxList"
            DataTextField="GroupName" DataValueField="GroupName" 
                onclick="readCheckBoxList()" >               
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

here is the button:

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                            CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" OnClientClick="return Validate_Checkbox()" />
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Should be in JS, rather than in code behind

Comment: It is better to do this kind of check on the client side using javascript. There is nothing here that depends on data from server

Comment: @both It is really trivially easy to bypass client side validation. It is perfectly reasonable to want code behind validation.

Comment: The alert part is what am worried about not the checking. Check is already in the answer. Probably put a label on the page and set the text property to your error message. `<asp:Label ForeColor="Red" />`

Comment: @codingbiz +1 for reading comprehension. I didn't even notice that. Asker: are you trying for client side or server side validation?

Comment: either client side or server side will work for me and i already tried jquery but i had some issues with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit:

Here is one sample code. its working to me

Must add this script file :`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Validate_Checkbox() {
            var chks = $("#<%= cblCustomerList.ClientID %> input:checkbox");          

            var hasChecked = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
                if (chks[i].checked) {
                    hasChecked = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (hasChecked == false) {
                alert("Please select at least one checkbox..!");

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }     
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblCustomerList" runat="server" CssClass="CheckBoxList">
            <asp:ListItem Value="0">xx</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">yy</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
        <asp:Button ID="xx" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:Validate_Checkbox();return true;" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and you change

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblCustomerList" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CssClass="CheckBoxList" DataTextField="GroupName" DataValueField="GroupName">             
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

control  instead of  my sample code . and call the `javascript function` in the button control.look my sample code.

Chears!!!

Edit

please add this script file

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Instead of `<script src="scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: my control id is called cblCustomerList where are you calling that in the javascript? here is my checkboxlist in aspx:  <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblCustomerList" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CssClass="CheckBoxList"
            DataTextField="GroupName" DataValueField="GroupName" 
                onclick="readCheckBoxList()" >               
            </asp:CheckBoxList>

Comment: I have new edited code above .please check the new code. its working

Comment: thanks but it is showing the alert eventhough i have selected one item.  i am not sure what is going on please help thanks

Comment: Hey my new Edit code is working fine in my local. You just change check box control .

Comment: i am getting different error that reads like this:"Error: Object doesn't support this property or method".  the OnClientClick is not tied to the checkboxlist but it is tied to a button.  pls. see my updated code above. thanks

Comment: Are you assign this script file??


<script src="scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I think the 1.8.3 min version script not have you. So just add this script 

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

instead of my script 

and i also now changed new code.You can try my new code.its working to me.any doubt .please let me. i am waiting

Comment: it worked like a charm even though i used <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>.  Your revised code worked very nice.  thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 13):

```
if(cblCustomerList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Any(item => item.Selected))
{
   // at least one selected
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this;

```
boolean b = cblCustomerList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Any(i => i.Selected)
```

if `b` is `true`, at least one is selected in your checkboxlist.

Don't forget to use `System.Linq` namespace.

Answer (score 4):

```
// using System.Linq;

// Considering that items are of ListItem type, otherwise use Cast<ListItem>()
if (!cblCustomerList.Items.Any(i => i.Selected))
{
    // TODO: Warn an user
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You would just use `cblCustomerList.SelectedItem == null`, SelectedItem will return the lowest ordinal item in the list of checked items, so if nothing is returned, nothing is checked.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
        if(! cblCustomerList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().AsParallel().Any(i => i.Selected))
        {
           ShowAlert("Please select at least one option");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery solution.

```
if (!$(".CheckBoxList").find("input:checked").length) {
    alert("Houston, we've had a problem!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way i can think of....

```
public void alert()
        {
            int i=0;
            foreach (ListItem listItem in cblCustomerList.Items)
            {
                if (listItem.Selected)
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }
            if(i !=0)
            {
                Response.Write("Please check at least one option");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using built-in 'CheckedItems':

```
 dim x1 As Integer = clbMoveTo.CheckedItems.Count
 If x1 <= 0 Then
     MessageBox.Show("Select Move To.","Verify")
     return
  End If
```